# Why does __attribute__(( constructor)) produce a dyld link error on OS X

Tags: macos, constructor, osx-yosemite, dlopen, dyld

This is my simple file `a.c` that I compile into a shared library:

```
void   b(void)
{
}


#ifdef HAVE_CONSTRUCTOR
__attribute__((constructor))
static void  a( void)
{
   b();
}
#endif
```

And this is the code `loader.c`, that loads the shared library:

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int  main( int argc, char *argv[])
{
   void   *handle;
   int    dlmode;

   dlmode = RTLD_LOCAL;
   handle = dlopen( argv[ 1], RTLD_LAZY|dlmode);
   if( ! handle)
   {
      fprintf( stderr, "error: failed to open \"%s\" %s\n",
                  argv[ 1], dlerror());
      return( 1);
   }

   return( 0);
}
```

The first try without the constructor works as expected:

```
$ clang -c a.c
$ clang -dynamiclib -flat_namespace a.o -o a.dylib
$ clang -o loader loader.c -ldl
$ ./loader a.dylib
$
```

But when I add the constructor, things fail:

```
$ clang -c -DHAVE_CONSTRUCTOR a.c
$ clang -dynamiclib -flat_namespace a.o -o a.dylib
$ ./loader a.dylib
 dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _b
  Referenced from: a.dylib
  Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: _b
  Referenced from: a.dylib
  Expected in: flat namespace

Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

It makes no sense to me. Why is **b** a plain C function not found ? I don't have a clue what to do about it.